# 'echo' calls .write function INFINITE times

Tags: linux, command-line, linux-kernel, echo, linux-device-driver

### Context

I wrote a Linux device driver in which the functions `read` and `write` are implemented. The problem is with the function write, here the portion of the code:

```
ssize_t LED_01_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{

    int retval = 0;
    PDEBUG(" reading from user space -> wrinting in kernel space\n");
    //struct hello_dev *dev = filp->private_data;
    if (count > COMMAND_MAX_LENGHT){
        printk(KERN_WARNING "[LEO] LED_01: trying to write more than possible. Aborting write\n");
        retval = -EFBIG;
        goto out;
    }
    if (down_interruptible(&(LED_01_devices->sem_LED_01))){
        printk(KERN_WARNING "[LEO] LED_01: Device was busy. Operation aborted\n");
        return -ERESTARTSYS;
    }
    if (copy_from_user((void*)&(LED_01_devices-> LED_value), buf, count)) {
        printk(KERN_WARNING "[LEO] LED_01: can't use copy_from_user. \n");
        retval = -EPERM;
        goto out_and_Vsem;
    }
    write_status_to_LED();
    PDEBUG(" Value instert: %u \n", LED_01_devices-> LED_value);


    out_and_Vsem:
    write_times++;
    up(&(LED_01_devices->sem_LED_01));
    out:
    return retval;
}
```

### Question

If I use the module in a C compiled program, **it works properly**, as expected.

When I execute `echo -n 1 > /dev/LED_01` (from the **Command LINE**), it writes INFINITE times and, even with the Ctrl+C it doesn't stop. I need to reboot.

Here the snipped code of the test function that works properly:

```
   // ON
   result = write(fd, (void*) ON_VALUE, 1);
   if ( result != 0 ){
       printf("Oh dear, something went wrong with write()! %s\n", strerror(errno));
   }
   else{
       printf("write operation executed succesfully (%u)\n",ON_VALUE[0]);
```

}

Is the problem in the driver or in the way I use `echo`?

If you need to whole source code, all the file used are stored [in this git repository folder](https://github.com/leos313/ldd3_training/tree/master/CHAPTER_09/LED_01)

Comment: weird. Did you try other methods, `printf 1 >...` or just plain `echo 1 > ...`? AND please confirm this is failing from the cmd-line, not inside of a shell script. Good luck.

Comment: echo 1 >.... it try to write also a \n and the driver was disegned to give an error if you try to write more that 1 unsigned int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value returned by the kernel's `.write` function is interpreted as:

- error code, if it is less than zero (`<0`),
- number of bytes written, if it is more than or equal to zero (`>=0`)

So, for tell user that all bytes has been written, `.write` function should return its `count` parameter.

---

In case of `.write` function, returning zero has a little sense: every "standard" utility like `echo` will just call `write()` function again.

Comment: exactly what I needed to know. So I just change return retval; with return count; in the case of success. And know I know how echo function manages the return values from functions. I guess that if it tries to write 100 characters and it receives 56 return value, it tries to write again and again the other 46 values. Isn't it?

Comment: Exactly. `echo` will try to write all remaining characters. Unless some `write()` call returns an error code (negative value).

Comment: However is it really strange that the process is unstoppable

Comment: It is not unstoppable - you may `kill` it. Also note, that unlike to user's code, wrong kernel's code may actually harm the whole system.